# Why these propositional statements are (basically) identical?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have this two statements:

1. $A$ if and only if $B$.
2. (Not $A$) if and only if (not $B$).

One of requests is to determine when these statements are true. Here is what I done:

[image: Truth table]

Then, it is also requested to explain why the two statements (1. and 2.) are basically identical.

Some ideas, suggestions?

Comment: You get a tautology: $A\Leftrightarrow B$ has the same "true table" as $-A\Leftrightarrow -B$. Thus both statements are equivalent by definition of equivalence of statements

Comment: Thanks, @sinbadh. Could you give a real world example of a application of this tautology?

Comment: Example: you pass the course if and only if the average score on your exams and papers is $65\%$ or greater. You fail the course if and only if your average score is less than $65\%$.

Answer (score 1):

$A \!\iff\! B$ is true precisely when $A$ and $B$ have the same truth value.  Thus, the truth value of $A \!\iff\! B$ is the same as that of $\neg A \!\iff\! \neg B$, whatever $A$ and $B$ may be — that's to say, the two formulas have the same truth table.